# How to pass props through an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On **FilterScreen** I have list of filters to select. **Filters.js** has Array of filter components and component with selected Filter. How to pass props to these filter components in array?

```
//Filters.js
const Filters = [
    <Filter1 />,
    <Filter2 />,
    ...,
]

export const MyFilter = props => Filters[props.filterIndex]
```

```
//FilterScreen.js
...

<MyFilter filterIndex={this.state.filterIndex} />

...
```

I want to pass opacity prop in MyFilter component and use the value in Filter1 component.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn `Filters` into a component itself, and then `spread` the `props` in children like this

```
const Filters = ({customProp, ...rest}) =>([
    <Filter1 {...rest} />,
    <Filter2 {...rest} customProp={customProp} />
])
```

And use it like this

```
export const MyFilter = props => <Filters  customProp='foo' filterIndex={props.filterIndex} />
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for because in your answer MyFilter turns into two filters and I want to select one depending on filterIndex.